Is Elden Ring on PC considered to be worse than the console versions?
I watched this video (0:58) today where the narrator mentioned frequent frame rate drops and glitchy graphics (among other things) on the PC port of Elden Ring. The narrator concluded that the PC port was very bad, leading them to purchase the game on their PS5 instead.
However, I am wondering if it is as bad as it was made out to be? How does it compare to the console variants (especially the PS5) in terms of stability and performance? The game also has a HDR toggle switch. What impact would that have?
I would be purchasing the game through Steam, in case platform factors into this at all. I'm running Windows 11, I have a GeForce RTX 2060 (it says so in Device Manager under Display Adaptors), in settings it says I have a AMD Ryzen 7 4800H with Radeon Graphics processor (according to Device Specifications), and 16 gigs of installed RAM.
Sorry about the unclear PC specs, it's my first time trying to figure those out.

Steam allows refunds, why don't you purchase it and try on your own machine? I believe some players manage to enjoy the game on their PCs just fine

I ended up buying the game and the Shadow of the Erdtree DLC, and I noticed very minor issues.
Three times, the game would freeze for a couple seconds, during which no frames had elapsed, meaning I didn't wake up dead. Also, twice the game dropped to maybe 20 FPS, where it stayed for about 10 seconds before the game warned me that my frame rate was too low for online play and put me on offline play.
I've played the game for maybe 15 hours so far, and these events are extremely rare and didn't cause me any inconveniences (besides not being able to read other's messages and leave my own).
Also, turning on HDR doesn't impact FPS or have any other performance impact at all, from what I can tell.
Apart from these very small things, which didn't subtract from the experience at all for me, the game runs beautifully.

No, it is not bad on PC, although you would only be able to draw a conclusion after testing for yourself. Such questions will always be dependent on your PC build, settings, etc. It makes no sense to ask such a blanket question.
Are your drivers updated? Is your OS updated? Is your rig modern or 20 years old? Elden Ring requires at least 12GB of RAM, which is 'high' compared to a lot of games. Again, all these things matter in the PC world, whereas none do for consoles.
Consoles are locked behind major/minor updates that get forced to the whole community. PC allows you to change/fix anything, plus: modders are wizards, and usually good enough to change/fix anything broken in the meantime.
In my opinion it's not much of a question: PC is always the optimal route.

Yes, but I've read some Reddit posts and similar things about how when the PC port came out, it wasn't great, even though they claimed to have good rigs, and that playing on PS was way better.

No console version of any game will ever beat the PC version, if it does it can be fixed and even improved beyond the console version with mods.

Hi Smokey. Why "cynicism", why not being critical; why go through the trouble when you know something could be wrong? Besides, there have been many games that were ported badly, and objectively played terribly on whatever platform they were ported to. There is also nothing inherently "optimal" about running games on the PC, it's just that PCs can have consumer hardware surpassing that of consoles in terms of capabilities. If you only want to criticize a question, please do so constructively (and nicely!) in a comment (see our CoC for guidance).
